# function which returns 0 when applied to 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, terminology

I am looking for a term describing a property of a function to return 0 when applied to zero: `f(0) = 0`. Perhaps there is some algebraic structure like a monoid?

Comment: I like your suggestion. Would you like to post it as an answer, so I can accept it is a solution? Thanks!

Comment: So, $f$ maps $0$ to $0$ but does anything to other values?  It's hard to see that's worthy of a special name beyond what M Winter suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply call them "functions with the fixed point $0$" or if your $f$ is defined on some euclidean space you can say that it "passes through the origin".

Answer (score 0):

These are the homomorphisms between algebraic structures with a single constant operation (happened to be named $0$). 
These structures are also called *pointed sets*.

Any homomorphism between algebraic structures whose signature has a constant operation, has to satisfy this property (fixing the constant symbols).

Comment: Thanks! This totally makes sense. Although I was hoping there is a simpler term not involving category theory.  Something like "idempotence"